# Python-Spark IllegalArgumentException when load CSV to DataFrame with DateType by spark-csv_2.10-1.3.0

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am trying to load csv file to dataframe by using spark-csv_2.10-1.3.0

```
sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
               .options(header='true',dateFormat='dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm')
               .load('test.csv',schema = s_acr_rv_derivative_schema)
```

the schema:

```
s_acr_rv_derivative_schema = StructType([
        StructField("COUNTERPARTY", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ORIG_COUNTERPARTY", StringType(), True),
        StructField("CUSTOMER_NAME", StringType(), True),
        StructField("TRADE_ID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("TRADE_DATE", DateType(), True)]
```

Issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:140)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.util.TypeCast$.castTo(TypeCast.scala:64)
```

Comment: btw, the datetime string is "25/04/2014 00:00"